# Struts2 : use of roles

Tags: servlets, struts2, roles

I'm working on a small Java EE application using Struts 2, which i have 2 different users with different roles (Admin & Member).

```
//Member
class Member extends User {
    //...
}

//Admin
class Admin extends User {
    //...
}
```

I have to distinguish between "member" and "admin" roles in order to stop member from using some Actions, or show some extract options to admin. so I found that i should use **RolesInterceptor**.
So i added it to my Action in my **struts.xml**.

```
<action name="dashboard" class="com.examples.DashboardAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="completeStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="roles">
        <param name="allowedRoles">admin</param>
        <param name="disallowedRoles">member</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">dashboard.jsp</result>
</action>
```

My question is how to declare to struts that **Admin** and **Member** classes have the following roles "admin" & "member".

Edit: i found some articles recommend the use of **PrincipalProxy** and **PrincipalAware** interfaces that allows indirect access to **HttpServletRequest**, but i don't know how to combine all this.

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html.